# Read out serial device via cat and hterm, different results

Tags: linux

I try to read out a serial device. I am working on an Ubuntu 12.04. The device is sending in equivalent time distances some Bits.

I connect to the device via Hterm and I can see the correctly incoming data.

If I read out the device via the linux command cat, there are several Bits missing.

My third method was to write a little C-file

```
struct termios options;

int main(void)
{
   int fd; /* File descriptor for the port */
   fd = open(DEVICE, O_RDWR | O_NONBLOCK);
   if (fd < 0)
   {
   /*
   * Could not open the port.
   */
       perror("open_port: Unable to open /dev/ttyACM3 - ");
   }

   fd_set read_fds, write_fds, except_fds;
   FD_ZERO(&read_fds);
   FD_ZERO(&write_fds);
   FD_ZERO(&except_fds);
   FD_SET(fd,&read_fds);

   struct timeval timeout;
   timeout.tv_sec = 10;
   timeout.tv_usec = 0;



   if(select(fd + 1, &read_fds, &write_fds, &except_fds, &timeout) == 1){
      char replay[DEBUG_REPLAY_MAX_SIZE];
      memset(replay, 0x00, DEBUG_REPLAY_MAX_SIZE);
      read(fd, &replay, DEBUG_REPLAY_MAX_SIZE);
      printf("Daten: %s", replay);
   }
   else{
      puts("Timeout");
   }
 return (fd);
}
```

This code should do the following:
- open serial device and return file descriptor
- the function select() waits a maximum time of 10 s listening there are comming some data in

But if I execute the c-file do not wait 10 s, but prints only "Daten:" with no following datas. Really strange.

Can someone explain this behaviour?

Thanks a lot,

Florian